# Get a list of all number in a certain range containing only certain digits without checking each number

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a way to create a list of all numbers less than 10,000 that do not contain any of the digits 0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8? Of course one can simply type something like:

```
bads = ['0', '2', '4', '5', '6', '8'] 
goods = []

for n in range(1, 10000, 2):
    if not any(bad in str(n) for bad in bads):
        goods.append(n)
```

However, I'm looking for a method which instead considers the digits 1, 3, 7, 9 and creates all possible unique strings of permutations of these numbers of size 4 or less, duplicate digits allowed. Does itertools, for example, have something that would easily do this? I looked at the permutations method, but that doesn't produce numbers with repeated digits from the collection, and the product method doesn't seem to be what I'm after either, given that it simply would return Cartesian products of 1, 3, 5, 7 with itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple-minded approach using `permutations` and `combinations_with_replacement` from itertools:

```
from itertools import permutations, combinations_with_replacement

def digit_combinations(power_of_ten):
    numbers = set()

    for n in range(1, power_of_ten + 1):
        for combination in combinations_with_replacement("1379", n):
            numbers |= set(permutations(combination, len(combination)))

    return sorted(int(''.join(number)) for number in numbers)

print(digit_combinations(4))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[1, 3, 7, 9, 11, 13, 17, 19, ..., 9971, 9973, 9977, 9979, 9991, 9993, 9997, 9999]
```

It could be made more space efficient using generators, but depending on the range, it might not be worth it.  (For up to 10,000 there are only 340 numbers.)  For numbers to 10^4, this code takes roughly as long as your simple example.  But for 10^7, this code runs over 40x faster on my system than your simple example.

> Could you include your idea for the generator?

Here's a basic rework of the code above into generator form:

```
from itertools import permutations, combinations_with_replacement

def digit_combinations_generator(power_of_ten):
    for n in range(1, power_of_ten + 1):
        for combination in combinations_with_replacement("1379", n):
            for number in set(permutations(combination, len(combination))):
                yield int(''.join(number))

generator = digit_combinations_generator(4)

while True:
    try:
        print(next(generator), end=', ')
    except StopIteration:
        print()
        break
```

This does *not* return the numbers sorted, it just hands them out as fast as it generates them.

Comment: Excellent. I'll probably just make this a generator just because, but I hadn't noticed combinations_with_replacement before! Thank you.

Comment: Could you include your idea for the generator?

Comment: @JohnnyApple, I've added a generator variant but I can't say that it's an improvement over my original function except it never creates a list of all the candidate numbers.

Comment: Excellent. That is almost an exact copy of what I made. The issue with the generator is that it's perfectly ok with producing duplicates!